# asynchronous programming using callbacks in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

I would like to know how can we do asynchronous programing in android, I read that asynchronous programming is not necessarily multithreaded(where this applies?), how can we do it in android because android has only main thread, if I do some heavy tasks in callbacks can I ensure I would not block main thread? what about other languages how they ensure responsive while using callbacks, are they also create new thread when doing asynchronous programming using callbacks?

and can we say parallel programming as mutithreaded programming?

Comment: If you search in google you will get something like this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: yes I know about this, I just wanted to for asynchronous programming is it necessary to create separate thread? how other programming languages like javascript carry asynchrous programming? are they also create separate thread? also multithreaded is same as parallel programming?

Answer (score 0):

yes in android there is a main thread on which all of your application Ui is running and if you try to do heavy tasks on that thread then it will be blocked and will not be user responsive that is a bad thing so you have to do multithreading there are several options for multithreading you can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a simple Thread or Handler Thread.

and can we say parallel programming as mutithreaded programming?

Answer : Yes.